# Looking for a mouseover sound script

Tags: javascript, button, audio, mouseover, wav

I'm looking for a a mouseover sound script (for button).
I plan to use wav sound but it can be another sound format.

Those I have found on the net are not compatible with new browser version.
I especially it need to work in Firefox.

I have found one on Jquery site but it requires Flash.

I prefer using only javascript if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to make it work under Firefox, so I decide to use Flash at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but JavaScript cannot play sound.  You'll find it easiest to work with Flash since it's so commonly installed in browsers.  JavaScript can interact with SWFs through the `ExternalInterface` ActionScript API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
thissound.Play();
}
</script>
<embed src="mysound.wav" autostart=false width=0 height=0 id="mysound" enablejavascript="true">
```

Then, to play on mouseover of a link, add the code:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="EvalSound('mysound')">Move mouse here</A>
```

Comment: I was not able to use this script, maybe I just not use it the correct way, I have found other similar scripts with same result.
I decide to use Flash finally.